# Unable to enable the Apache2 user www-data

Tags: magento2, file-permissions

After completing the Magento 2.0.0 rc and creating the user 'www-data' for the root installation drive /var/www/html I was unable to run the following command.

Enable Apache user ->**sudo chsh -s /bin/bash www-data**
Set the user’s password -> **sudo passwd www-data**
Trying to take ownership of my Magento2 files using 'www-data' user -> **chown -R www-data .**

Received a very large list of errors either **Operation not permitted or Permission denied**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you change the ownership using root (sudo)?

Answer (score 1):

I do the following on Debian 7/8:

#### Step 1

`passwd www-data`
Set a password.

#### Step 2

`sed -i 's/www\-data:\/var\/www:\/usr\/sbin\/nologin/www\-data:\/var\/www:\/bin\/bash/' /etc/passwd`

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried your steps above and my result is given below

_passwd: You may not view or modify password information for www-data._

I'm using Ubuntu 14 AMI from AWS and the user is Ubuntu

Comment: You should run these commands with the `root` privileges.